Implementing Internationalization (i18n) in Django
How can I effectively utilize internationalization (i18n) in Django Metronic to make my web application accessible in multiple languages?
I'm struggling to implement i18n in my Django project with the Metronic theme. Despite configuring settings and marking strings for translation, I'm facing issues with translations not reflecting correctly and language switching not working as expected.

i18 has nothing to do with the theme I think. apply the same settings from the documentation

maybe you can share how you have set up your stuff. It will make things much easier to you debug the issue

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
